# Strange StackOverflow when using SlidingMenu

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow, slidingmenu

I have an activity that uses a simple `ViewPager` to navigate through different fragments. However, whenever I call `setCurrentItem` with the smooth scrolling set to `true` the app lags for a few seconds and then displays the requested fragment. Surprisingly, dragging works fine without any lags.

The app doesn't crash on higher end devices like the N5, but it does crash on lower end devices, so I was able to get a log of what has been happening. The error seems to be coming from the `CustomViewAbove.java` file from the `slidingmenu` library.

I tried removing the sliding menu temporarily and the issue was fixed, however it came back again when I re-enabled the slide-out menu, so I'm sure it has to do something with the library.

It is strange because it was working fine with the same set-up yesterday.

Here is the crash log:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:105)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:442)
at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1025)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14022)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3080)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12821)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12879)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12879)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2357)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3698)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3080)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12821)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3080)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12821)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2171)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.dispatchDraw(CustomViewAbove.java:828)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12879)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12879)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12879)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13735)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3106)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14025)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2236)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12884)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12926)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.buildDisplayList(HardwareRenderer.java:1411)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1359)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2456)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2273)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1034)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5632)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any ideas about what might be causing the issue?

Comment: can you able to post you code where you are setting your image??

Comment: @Sreekanth images are loaded and displayed using `UniversalImageLoader` but I doubt it has to do something with it since if I remove the `slidingmenu` everything will be fixed

Comment: Try to flatten your view-hierarchy. This fixed the StackOverflowException for me.

Comment: @KlassenK the view hierarchy is pretty simple. It's just a `ViewPager`. The hosted fragments only contain a `ListView` as well, so there's no space for more optimization.

Comment: Also it was working fine just this morning with the exact same set-up

Comment: some times I encountered similar problems due to too high image resolutions that the device couldn't handle. Anyway, what's in `CustomViewAbove.java:828`?